# Groovy Substrings Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have an environment variable in Jenkins and want to save the rest of the variable from the 4th character onwards into a new variable.

e.g. myvar = "abcdefghi"

I need everything after the 4 characters up to N so: fghi

My Jenkinsfile currently looks like I want to use a substring unfortunately the code doesn't work I have a bug somewhere in the variable?

```
pipeline{
    agent {
        label 'windows'
    }
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '15'))
    }
    environment {
        get_tag = """${bat(
            script: '@git describe --tags --abbrev=0', 
            returnStdout: true
            )}"""
        type = "${get_tag[0..1]}"
        count = "${get_tag[3,4]}"
        branch = "${GIT_BRANCH}"
        temppath = 'E:\\Temp\\'
    }
    stages {
        stage('info'){
            steps{
              script {
                def ver = "${get_tag.substring(4)}"
                def version = ver.split("_")
              }
            }
        }
```

error : 1.

No such property: version for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: After the fourth character would be `efghi`.  Or do you want the last four characters?  But anyway: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-

Comment: What kind of error your pipeline produces? What happens when you run it? Please paste the console log.

Comment: @cfrick I would like the last four characters.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak 1.

No such property: version for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: Please add the full console log, remove any sensitive data. The error message you added does not match anything from your pipeline script.

Comment: You can use `get_tag[4..-1]`

Answer (score 2):

to get last 4 chars you could use groovy range access:

```
def myvar = "abcdefghi"
def last4 = myvar[-4..-1]
```

results `fghi`